# How to copy files to host-mounted directory in docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm trying to copy configuration files to jenkins/jenkins image with host mounted directory.
part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
COPY file.txt /var/jenkins_home/
```

Tried to use volume like this:

```
-v volume_name:/var/jenkins_home
```

in this case i do see "file.txt" in jenkins, but if i use:

```
-v /folder:/var/jenkins_home
```

i do not see file.txt in jenkins at all. so what am i miss here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Per your question:**

> ... if i use:
>
> ```
> -v /folder:/var/jenkins_home
> ```
>
> i do not see file.txt in jenkins at all. so what am i miss here?

Host volumes, sometimes referred to as bind mounts because of their underlying implementation, do not initialize the volume from the image content. Only named volumes provide a initialization support from the docker engine. However, it is possible to perform a named volume to a bind mount with a different syntax. Here are several examples of different ways to do that:

```
  # create the volume in advance
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=none \
      --opt device=/home/user/test \
      --opt o=bind \
      test_vol

  # create on the fly with --mount
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/home/user/test \
    foo

  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    bind-test:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /home/user/test
  ...
```

In your case, you could do:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  --mount type=volume,dst=/var/jenkins_home,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/folder \
  ...
```

---

**To answer what you are actually trying to do:**

That said, the Jenkins image defins a volume at /var/jenkins_home which blocks your ability to extend the image with a RUN command that changes that folder. COPY and ADD just happen to work because they do not create a temporary container. As a workaround, Jenkins developers use `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` inside the image as a source to initialize the /var/jenkins_home directory. So your Dockerfile should copy your desired files there instead:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
COPY file.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/
```

Comment: Yes, using /usr/share/jenkins/ref/ did the work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

In your first scenario you're telling docker to create a Volume (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and mount it on `/var/jenkins_home`, 
docker pre-populates the volume with the data that's already existing in the docker image. If the volume already existed it will reuse it.

You can check your volumes by executing:

```
docker volume ls
```

In your second scenario you're not seeing the file because you're bind mounting (https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a directory from your host (local machine / vm) to the container. All the files that you see under `/var/jenkins_home` will be the same as in your host directory `/folder`.

This happens at runtime (when container is created), if you want to have some default files in your docker image you do this at build time by using the `COPY` or `ADD` instructions, like you're doing, these files will be copied over to the image when you build it. But if at runtime you specify a bind mount of the directory or the file you are basically replacing them.

Comment: This is exactly what i did - tried both COPY and ADD - but in second scenario i do not see those copied files at all

Comment: It's important to differentiate between what you're doing at build time and what you're doing at runtime. In this case in your Dockerfile you're copying some files to a directory. Those files are there in your image. But if you, at runtime are bind mounting a directory from your host to the container, to the location where those files were placed at build time, docker won't copy the existing files to the directory in your host, it will only show the existing contents of the mounted folder.